# I want to scrape the link from the html code below, but do not know how to do that because it is in the brackets

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, python-3.7, screen-scraping

This is the html code from which I want to scrape the link of the youtube video. But I do not know how to do it, if anyone of you know this please answer me.

```
<button  id='btnWatchLikeAndSubscribe' class='greenButton button' style='font- 
size: 18px;'                             
onclick="newtab =openWin('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZenDvvS5WM'); 
enableWatchTimer();">1. 
<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>&nbsp Watch, Like &amp; Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expression:

```
import re
match = re.search(r'''openWin\(('(?P<url>[^']*)')\)''',TEXT_OF_BUTTON)
url = match.groupdict().get('url') if match else None
```

Comment: What do you mean by TEXT OF BUTTON?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out and it worked.